# How to uninstall Firebase CLI (firebase-tools)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I install Firebase CLI (firebase-tools) https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools by this code:

```
curl -sL firebase.tools | bash
```

How to uninstall it totally?

Comment: You might want to post an issue on the GitHub that you linked to so they can update the documentation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can type `which firebase` on the command line and check the location. Then `rm <location>`

on mac the location is `/usr/local/bin/firebase`

Comment: Thanks. I can find it. It's 109.3 MB. Can this way remove firebase totally?

Comment: To actually delete: `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/firebase`

Comment: see below for a better method for those who installed with npm install -g firebase-tools. Short answer: npm uninstall -g firebase-tools

Comment: npm uninstall -g firebase-tools does not work in all cases. Just do that then run firebase then you'll see it wasn't uninstalled. The @douglas.iacovelli solution is the one which actually works.

Comment: if you rm an executable, dont forget to run `hash -r` to rebuild the index of executables, otherwise you might get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/firebase: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 28):

If you install firebase like
`curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash`

Just use this to uninstall.
`curl -sL firebase.tools | uninstall=true bash`

Comment: I'm gonna vote for this because it's probably the most future proof

Answer (score 24):

Run:

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: npm uninstall -g firebase-tools does not work in all cases. Just do that then run firebase then you'll see it wasn't uninstalled. The @douglas.iacovelli solution is the one which actually works.

Comment: This is not related to the method of installation that the original poster has specified.

Answer (score 12):

Just for people who installed firebase via

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

typing `which firebase` and `rm <location>` as in the first answer will not uninstall all components.

You should uninstall via

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
```

as recommended in the second answer.

Comment: npm uninstall -g firebase-tools does not work in all cases. Just do that then run firebase then you'll see it wasn't uninstalled. The @douglas.iacovelli solution is the one which actually works.