# Firebase - this dependency was not found

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting this error but I don't know why. It is vue app, I npm installed Firebase, then I created my `firebaseConfig.js` where is my api key and other data as in docs.. then I have my `firebaseInit.js` with this code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

in my package json I have this dependency:

```
 "firebase": "^9.6.4",
```

and this is what I get as an error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* firebase in ./src/components/firebaseInit.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save firebase
```

Comment: Did you try running the command from the error message, `npm install --save firebase`? Does it solve the issue?

Comment: @FaridSchumbar i did and it didnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be resolved by reinstalling the dependency, in case it's not installed properly:

try to [uninstall it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386943/how-to-uninstall-firebase-cli-firebase-tools) first and then reinstall with `npm install --save firebase`.

Also, have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062656/cannot-install-firebase-for-vuejs-nodejs) - the same problem was fixed by removing the `^` sign, i. e. replace `"firebase": "^9.6.4"` with `"firebase": "9.6.4"`.